# Select default value in select box while using c:forEach tag

Tags: jquery, jsp, spring-mvc

I have the following code in a JSP

```
<select id="product" name="product" class="width400 select" size="4" disabled="disabled">
    <c:forEach  items="${sch}" var="obj">
        <option value="${obj.product}" ${selectedSchedule.product == obj.product ? 'selected' : ''}>${obj.product}</option>
    <c:forEach> 
</select>
```

I want the select box to highlight the first option. The items in `sch` are the result of a select query. `selectedSchedule` is being passed a POJO object for modelling. For some reason the value isn't being selected. Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your option tag doesn't look right - the JSTL will produce `<option value="foo" selected>` but it should look like `<option value="foo" selected="selected">`... try:

```
<option value="${obj.product}" ${selectedSchedule.product == obj.product ? 'selected="selected"' : ''}>${obj.product}</option>
```